# How do the new iOS 9 ad blocking apps work, exactly?

Tags: ios9, adblock

Traditional ad blockers on desktop web work in one of two ways:

1) Detecting http calls and blocking any calls that include a text string that matches any entry on their "blacklist" which is often defined by Easy List or some other UGC list of sites.

2) Elements on the page are hidden based on some rule that reads the markup and applies CSS accordingly.

The question is, how do the new iOS 9 ad blockers (such as [Crystal](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/crystal-block-ads-browse-faster./id1022177308?mt=8), [1Blocker](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/1blocker-block-ads-tracking/id1025729002?mt=8), [Blockr](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/blockr-privacy-media-ad-blocker/id1032344361?mt=8), etc.) work? My understanding is that an iOS app cannot detect the http calls coming from another app, and that option 1 is therefore out the window - is this correct?

If the new ad blockers use option 2, then is there any standard list of rules that ad blockers use to identify a page element as an ad and hide it?

EDIT:

See Developer Documentation here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_9_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014305-CH9-SW8

Section titled "Content blocking Safari extensions"

Comment: Please update with any documentation you find, it will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Content Blockers on iOS work by supplying the safari browser with a JSON array of triggers and actions. Actions can either apply custom CSS, or block the load of a resource:

See Apple's [Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_9.html) (Scroll down to the section titled “Content Blocking Safari Extensions”), as well as this presentation given at the most recent WWDC: [Safari Extensibility: Content Blocking and Shared Links](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=511).

Comment: You just added what he put in his edit, which he did first. Down voted.